# SharePoint 2013 - download a copy option and open with explorer option disabled

Tags: download

Does anyone know why SharePoint 2013 - hosted on-prem does not allow to download files when opened using an external URL.

Which permissions do I need to enable to allow users to download a copy.
OR
Open with Explorer.

Regards
Nitin